# Android - Interface design

Tags: android, background, size, screen, resolution

I have the following problem:

I'm developing an Android Application and the main screen have a big image with 5 small images with specific location on the screen. The problem is, I want to put that small images like buttons, clickable.

I try put a big image with everything and put a invisible button on the small images but it doesn't because the place of the invisible button changes with different resolutions. I try to separate the small images and add them like image buttons on specific positions, but in different resolutions they change the location and don't stay where I want.

What is the easiest way to put the small images on that place and lock the position for every devices ?

Best Regards

Comment: if either answer helped you please mark it as accepted (by clicking the checkmark next to it) - this affects reputation of the author.

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate relative offsets and use margins to position your ImageButtons and use **dp** (density-independent pixels) when doing so. This will ensure proper positioning due to dps being scaled to screen density uniformly with resources.

More on dps here: http://blog.edwinevans.me/?p=131. Afaik, 1dp equals 1 real pixel for mdpi density, 1.5 for hdpi and 2.0 for xhdpi. So, do your calculations on mdpi background, set margins in dp and the rest should resolve itself.

PS Better solution would be to use background image that doesn't constraint button positioning and use standard spacing amount to position buttons. Android design guidelines suggest using 48px "rhythm" when laying out anything: http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html

Answer (score 0):

In your case, instead of using invisible buttons, using image buttons seems to be more appropriate.
Here is an example how to add image buttons in Eclipse ;

http://blog.jamware.biz/2009/11/how-to-add-image-button.html

Comment: I use imagebutton ... but the problem is that I can't put in same location for all devices, they change of place.

Answer (score 0):

[You can use an imagebutton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) instead of using an invisible button with an image on top.

Comment: I use imagebutton ... but the problem is that I can't put in same location for all devices, they change of place.

Comment: you can use relative layout to set margin and position of components relatively to each other